How can I write a formula for the orbital velocity of the moon?
From NASA
Dec 22,1999 11:00 356655 km moon at perigee
Jan 19, 2000 22:46 359363 km moon at perigee
I choose those dates because December 22nd is the winter solstice, so the line of apsides would point right at the sun.
In one month the earth moves about 30° in orbit around the sun.  By geometry this leads to an ellipse central angle in the earth moon frame of $ \phi $ = 27.64°.  I used a program to solve for the elliptic integral E($\phi$,e), where e is the eccentricity of the moon's orbit e=.0549, and it gave me .482355  I multiplied that by the semi major axis a=384400 km to get the arc length S traveled by the moon from anomalistic month to synodic month.  S=185427 km.  I then guessed at the orbital velocity 1.06 km/s noting it would be slightly less than its maximum 1.082 km per sec.  This gave me an additional transit time of 185417/1.06= 174921 sec= 2.02 days.  Adding the anomalistic month 27.55455 days + 2.02 days = 29.579 days.  Compare to NASA's 29.675 days. My problem is I guessed at the instantaneous orbital velocity, and I want to determine it mathematically.  Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: Using the vis-viva equation you get an orbital speed of 1.09 km/s on December 22, and 1.02 km/s on January 19.  The average speed of the moon for that month was 1.055 km/s. So now we have 185417/1.055 = 175751 sec = 2.03 days.  27.55455+2.03=29.588 days.  To get NASA'S value I have to have the velocity as a function of distance and integrate.

See vis-viva equation

@EricTowers, that works.  I plugged in NASA'S value for moon at perigee on December 22 and got 1.09, km/s and for January 19 got 1.02 km/s.  Thanks.  The average is 1.055 km/s.

Yes the vis-viva equation. For those who care ; Proposed by Gottfried Leibniz over the period 1676–1689, the theory was controversial as it seemed to oppose the theory of conservation of quantity of motion advocated by René Descartes.

As you have shown, calculating the length of the path does not solve the problem.
One of Kepler's laws is that a line from the focus of the orbit to the orbiting body traces out equal areas in equal times. This was later shown to be a consequence of the conservation of angular momentum. It also leads eventually to the conclusion that the orbital period does not actually depend on the eccentricity of the orbit. The period depends on the gravitational constant, the semimajor axis of the orbit of one body relative to the other, and the sum of the masses of the bodies
according to the formula
$$ T = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{G(M_1+M_2)}}. $$
But that assumes we're dealing with a simple two-body problem, in which you have a fixed elliptical orbit. The orbit of the Moon around the Earth precesses, so it takes the Moon slightly longer to reach the next perigee (the anomalistic month) than to get around the Earth once relative to the stars (the sidereal month).
Also, the winter solstice is only near, not exactly on the line of apsides for the Earth-Sun system (perihelion is actually about two weeks after the solstice), and the line of apsides for the Earth-Sun system is unrelated to the line of apsides for the Earth-Moon system, which due to the previously-mentioned precession is constantly changing direction.
You may not have noticed, but the elapsed time between the two perigee events you cited is about $28.5$ days, almost a day longer than the mean anomalistic month ($27.55455$ days). The effects of precession on the apsides are not uniform.
Dealing with elliptical orbits is complicated. Dealing with elliptical orbits that precess in non-uniform ways is even more complicated.
Since the eccentricity of the Moon is so small, you might be able to get a reasonable approximation by assuming the line of apsides is about halfway between the two perigees.
You didn't say exactly where you got the figure $29.675$ days. It's longer than the mean synodic month but shorter than either of the synodic months that started in on December 7, 1999 or January 6, 2000.
In summary, you have a lot more to account for here than just the distance and time along a fixed elliptical orbit.
